# Redirect from HTTP to HTTPs in lighthttpd

Tags: http, redirection, https, lighttpd

How can I redirect from HTTP to HTTPS with `lighthttpd`?

There are tons of `lighttpd` config snippets floating around to make this happen, but so far none of these really worked. Currently I am still playing around with `127.0.0.1`, so if anyone has an adequate config in use, that would be great.

My lighttpd version is 1.4.29, OS Arch Linux 64bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
        ssl.engine = "enable"
        ssl.pemfile = "/path/to/pem/file/unknown.pem"
}


$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
        $HTTP["host"] =~ "(.*)" {
                url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://%1/$1" )
        }
}
```

solved it for me.

Comment: You might want to note that this also requires the use of `mod_redirect`, so adding the line `server.modules += ( "mod_redirect" )` to your config file may be necessary.  At least it was for me with lighttpd 1.4.55

Comment: Solved it for me too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this situation is have a small one-page site available through HTTP that contains a single page with a [meta refresh tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm) and possibly an explanation for browsers that have redirects disabled or unsupported for some reason.  Create a custom 404 error page that also does the same thing.

The meta tag should then redirect to `https://127.0.0.1` or your site's external address when you allow it to be externally reachable.

I would let the page display for 5 seconds using the meta refresh saying "This site is only available through HTTPS.  You should be automatically redirected in 5 seconds, if not click here..."

Comment: I get this when using url.redirect: (server.c.1550) WARNING: unknown config-key: url.redirect (ignored). Using lighttpd 1.4.54